# comparing 2 tables in laravel using join

Tags: php, laravel

So in literal term I'm trying to say "user_id should either be A_id or B_id".
A_id and B_id are 2 columns in trans table.
I could only do "user_id equal to A_id" and this is my function for it

```
$pending = User::join('trans', 'users.user_id' , '=', 'trans.A_id')
        ->where('user_id',$user_id)
        ->where('trans.status', 0)
        ->get();
```

please can someone help me rewrite this function to get what I'm trying to do?.

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer the question. Provide information on the table structure, and your model relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
$a_id=DB::table('trans')->pluck('A_id');
$b_id=DB::table('trans')->pluck('B_id');
User::where(function($query) {
    return $query->whereIn('user_id', $a_id)
    ->orWhereIn('user_id', $b_id);
})->get();
```